# How to run development and production nestjs app docker docker-compose

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, nestjs

I'm new with docker and I'm trying to build a container with development and production version of my api.

If I run the command "docker-compose up dev" everything works fine, but when I run the production command "docker-compose up prod" I get the following error:

```
[+] Running 2/2
 - Network sip-api_nestjs-network  Created                                                                                                                                                                                  0.7s 
 - Container api-prod              Created                                                                                                                                                                                  0.1s
Attaching to api-prod
api-prod  | 
api-prod  | > sip-api@0.0.1 start:prod
api-prod  | > node dist/main
api-prod  |
api-prod  | node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:959
api-prod  |   throw err;
api-prod  |   ^
api-prod  |
api-prod  | Error: Cannot find module '/app/dist/main'
api-prod  |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
api-prod  |     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
api-prod  |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
api-prod  |     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
api-prod  |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
api-prod  |   requireStack: []
api-prod  | }
api-prod exited with code 1
```

What I understand from the error is that it is not copying or creating the directories with the necessary files, but I am not sure.

````
This is my Dockerfile:

```
#############################
# BUILD FOR LOCAL DEVELOPMENT
#############################
FROM node:16-alpine AS development

USER node

WORKDIR /app

COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./

RUN npm ci

COPY --chown=node:node . .

######################
# BUILD FOR PRODUCTION
######################

FROM node:16-alpine AS build

USER node

WORKDIR /app

COPY --chown=node:node package*.json ./

COPY --chown=node:node --from=development /app/node_modules ./node_modules

COPY --chown=node:node . .

RUN npm run build

ENV NODE_ENV=production

RUN npm ci --only=production && npm cache clean --force

###################
# PRODUCTION
###################

FROM node:16-alpine AS production

COPY --chown=node:node --from=build /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --chown=node:node --from=build /app/views ./views
COPY --chown=node:node --from=build /app/dist ./dist

CMD [ "node", "dist/main.js" ]
````

```
This is my docker-compose.yml
```

```
version: '3.8'

services:

    dev:
        container_name: api-dev
        image: api-dev
        build:
            context: .
            target: development
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
        ports:
            - 3200:3200
            - 9229:9229
        networks:
            - nestjs-network
        working_dir: /app
        volumes:
            - ./:/app
            - /app/node_modules
        command: npm run start:dev
        restart: unless-stopped

    prod:
        container_name: api-prod
        image: api-prod
        build:
            context: .
            target: production
            dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
        ports:
            - 3200:3200
            - 9230:9230
        networks:
            - nestjs-network
        working_dir: /app
        volumes:
            - ./:/app
            - /app/node_modules
        command: npm run start:prod
        restart: unless-stopped

networks:
    nestjs-network:
```

```
Can anyone help me with this error? Thanks in advance
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the package.json
The command npm run start:prod was pointing to dist/main when it should point to dist/src/main
That was all

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify `WORKDIR /app` in your last build stage, all the files are being copied to root.

Comment: I try your solution @Anthony, but I get the same error: </br>'

FROM node:16-alpine AS production </br>

# Create app directory </br>
WORKDIR /app </br>

# Copy the bundled code to the production image </br>
COPY --chown=node:node --from=build /app/node_modules ./node_modules </br>
COPY --chown=node:node --from=build /app/views ./views </br>
COPY --chown=node:node --from=build /app/dist ./dist </br>

# Start the server using the production build </br>
CMD [ "node", "dist/main.js" ]'

Comment: Then either your build step is not building to the dist folder, or your CMD is pointing to the wrong directory. Why are you using `working_dir` anyways? It's always a better idea to put absolute paths in CMD. You also don't need `command` or `volumes` (unless there's something to persist) in prod, CMD already takes care of starting your app.